# Intellij scaladoc exception

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc

I'm using intellij community 2018.3 with scala 2.12. 
I try to generate scaladoc of my project (a library) but intellij print me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.allDirsByDottedName()Lscala/collection/Map;
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.findDirEntry(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.list(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:53)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.list$(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:52)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipAndJarClassPathFactory$ZipArchiveClassPath.list(ZipAndJarFileLookupFactory.scala:42)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$list$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:944)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:944)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1432)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.list(AggregateClassPath.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:271)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:220)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1535)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:225)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:36)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:267)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:267)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1179)
    at scala.tools.nsc.doc.DocFactory.makeUniverse(DocFactory.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.doc.DocFactory.generate$1(DocFactory.scala:124)
    at scala.tools.nsc.doc.DocFactory.document(DocFactory.scala:131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScalaDoc.process(ScalaDoc.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScalaDoc$.main(ScalaDoc.scala:92)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScalaDoc.main(ScalaDoc.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

IDE is update. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the following:

Also you are on scala 2.12, scala reflect seems to be on 2.11 or other version. 
Add a dependency to scala reflect to your project:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.8